# Windows Phone Background Audio stutters after GDR3 update

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-audio

I have a Windows Phone application, which can play music using Windows Phone Audio Playback Agent. It has deployed to Windows Phone Market and it worked fine until GDR3 update.

After update I have got the issue:
After 5-10 seconds of playback starts there is a short stuttering (for 1-2 seconds).

The using of Background Audio is pretty common:

```
      var url = new Uri("http://...");
      var track = new AudioTrack( url, "Title", "Artist", "Album", null, null, 
              EnabledPlayerControls.Pause | 
              EnabledPlayerControls.SkipPrevious |   
              EnabledPlayerControls.SkipNext);

      BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = track;
      BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
```

This issue has been reproduced at least on Lumia 720, Lumia 920, Lumia 925 models and only after GDR3 update.

Does anyone run into this annoying issue?

Many thanks in advance.